# Combining Javascript- and C# GUI

Tags: javascript, xaml, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, filesystems

I would like to make an application for displaying images from a local directory, however using a given javascript GUI framework for filtering the contents. How could this be done?

I tried with Windows 8 Store Application:
- Only Javascript / Html 5: I failed by reading the pictures from the pictureLibrary by javascript. Displaying the pictures is also difficult, as dynamic content is not allowed and most frameworks use it.
- Only Xaml/WinRT: How to integrate the Javascript GUI?
- Combinatin of both: Is there a way to use Javascript and Xaml GUIs together??

I know I could accomplish it with a webapplication, but I would like to program it for the desktop in an application way.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through [WinRT Components](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/509164/Building-WinRT-components-that-implement-interface), though I think it's easiear to write an entire HTML5 app and learn how to display images, easy as:

```
var pictureLibrary = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary;
pictureLibrary.getFilesAsync(query).then(function (items) {
 for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(items[i]);
    container.appendChild(image);
  }
};
```

Keeping in mind that "container" is where you want to display the images.